No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it. [Java, VSCode]
So me and two friends are doing a project for our high school comp sci class. We're using Swing to make GUIs, and hitting a few problems. We've hit a No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it. error, and I've never heard of an X11 DISPLAY, but following the error trail, it seems to be connected to a Headless Exception, about a missing display. I have a few vague ideas as to what it means, but it's not helping much.
We're currently coding in Visual Studio Code, and are connected to a Github Codespace. We have a file called Main.java, and the following code inside it:
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends Canvas implements KeyListener {
        public Main() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("ma pona");
                frame.add(this);
                frame.setSize(1000, 750);
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.addWindowListener(
                        new WindowAdapter() {
                            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                                System.exit(0);
                            }
                        });
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                new Main();
            }


Our specific error is:
Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: 
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:548)
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:423)
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:224)
        at Main.<init>(Main.java:8)
        at Main.main(Main.java:22)

If you could give any insight, that would be great. Thank you for your time.

The likely duplicate cited by @aled lets you run an X11 server locally that displays your code running on the GitHub client.

See also Initial Threads.
